# In Django, the button url is called unexpectedly, The url request is excuted differently

Tags: django, templates, url, href

In Django, the button url is called unexpectedly, so I can not find the page

I tried click below button but it's not work

```
<button type="button" 
        class="btn btn-outline-info btn-sm float-right" 
        name="button" 
        onclick="location.href='{{fn_id}}/finisher/new'">
            post
</button>
```

result of url request is

[image]

It seems that there is a problem because I made the url request when I was on the detail page.

and below buuton is work

```
<button
    type="button"
    class="btn btn-outline-info btn-sm float-right"
    name="button" onclick="location.href='http://127.0.0.1:8000/bestlec/{{fn_id}}/finisher/new'"
    >
        post
</button>
```

but That causes problem Because it requests a local address

do you know how to slove it?? thanks for let me know~!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, I expect you're on page `http://127.0.0.1:8000/bestlec/1`.  You've then given a relative url of `1/finisher/new` which has been added to the current url to give `http://127.0.0.1:8000/bestlec/1/1/finisher/new`.

If you want to give a relative url use `finisher/new`.  If you need to go to other ids use `/bestlec/{{fn_id}}/finisher/new` or better still, use `{% url 'url-name' fn_id %}`

Comment: I solved the problem ~! I was informed that the url was requested as expected. Thank you.